# seeing the stack and heap amounts used by threads of an application

Tags: multithreading, performance, memory

all

I have a Windows executable, containing 6 user threads.

How can I observe CPU usage, stack and heap usage of each thread ?

Özgür.

Comment: A thread doesn't 'own' memory in the heap.  Stack usage is simply number of threads x one megabyte.

Comment: I mean the heap allocated by the code running in each thread. Make sense ?

Comment: I'm not at all sure that the OS keeps any record of heap/s allocation per thread - why should it?  Per process for sure because it has to deallocate all the heaps, stacks etc. on app close. Stack - well the virtual memory manager should know how much VM and real RAM is allocated/committed, but I don't know how to get this outside of kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

Comment: I run it. Under performance tab, pyhsical memory info is presented.

Comment: Under Performance tab, I see Physical Memoty / Working Set ; Private / Shareable / Share numbers. What are they ? I can not see per thread information related to stack and heap usage.